# How to see Github container registry push history?

Tags: github-package-registry

There are multiple users with write access rights to Github Package.
There is a list of versions pushed, but I cannot find information on who pushed the particular version of the container image. Is it possible to find out who pushed an image?

I have admin rights to the package, I tried looking through Github Package version list, through package settings.